# No Such Column in SQLite Temporary Table Statement

Tags: sql, sqlite, db-browser-sqlite

I have two SQLite tables (`companies` and `complaints`) I'm using to calculate a ratio of HR complaints to employees, but when attempting to run the query below in DB Browser, I'm getting this error:

```
-- Result: no such column: complaints.hrcomplaints
```

Here's the SQL I'm using:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE newratio AS SELECT companies.uniqueID, employees, complaints.hrcomplaints,
       (ROUND(hrcomplaints * 100.0 / employees, 1)*.01) AS newratio
FROM companies
ORDER BY newratio
```

The column type for both `hrcomplaints` and `employees` is integer. I'm not seeing any extra whitespace in the column names when viewing the DB structure.

Comment: What is the relation between companies and complaints? Post the definitions of the tables.

Comment: @forpas, there is no relationship (primary key etc) between tables - I'm pretty new to SQL, is that what you are asking?

Comment: There should be a relationship. Tables consist of rows and columns. Which column value of hrcomplaints from complaints will be divided by which column value of `employees` (which is also not clear in which table it belongs)?